# show two or more links to the auto-write files from data in database

Tags: php, mysql

I am just learning how to auto write a new file from data in database. And I follow this tutorial: http://www.9lessons.info/2011/04/seo-friendly-urls-with-php.html

The tutorial just give me what I want to achieve. As soon as I posted a new post to database with the file of publish.php, the link of the new post/file I have posted will be seen in the top of the form. The auto rewrite url is got from the file of article.php.

It is the form:

```
<input type="text" name "title"/>
<textarea name="body"></teaxtarea>

<?php
include('db.php');

function string_limit_words($string, $word_limit) {
  $words = explode(' ', $string);
  return implode(' ', array_slice($words, 0, $word_limit));   
}
$blog='';

if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST")
{
$title=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['title']);
$body=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['body']);
$title=htmlentities($title);
$body=htmlentities($body);
$date=date("Y/m/d");

$newtitle=string_limit_words($title, 6);
$urltitle=preg_replace('/[^a-z0-9]/i',' ', $newtitle);

$newurltitle=str_replace(" ","-",$newtitle);
$url=$date.'/'.$newurltitle.'.html';


mysql_query("insert into blog(title,body,url) values('$title','$body','$url')");
$blogurl="http://seo.website.com/$url";

}

?>
```

Blow is the link to the new posted file.

```
<h2><a href="<?php echo $blogurl; ?>"><?php echo $blogurl; ?></a></h2>
```

What I want to know at this time is, how to show all the links of the data/file I have posted into database.

I have tried to copy paste the line above like this:

```
<h2><a href="<?php echo $blogurl; ?>"><?php echo $blogurl; ?></a></h2>
<h2><a href="<?php echo $blogurl; ?>"><?php echo $blogurl; ?></a></h2>
```

However it only show the same two links of one file from data in database, while what I want is it shows to different link of two files, for instance: the first link show the file number 1, and the second link show the file number 2 from data in database.

Please don't focus to database driver of mysql I use, I just still want to learn from this stage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

.. if I understand the question correctly - you need to get the values and loop through each one. In your question it looks like you are echoing the same values repeatedly.

```
(pcode)
$query = "select * from blog";
$ret = $pdo->do( $query );

$blogurl="http://seo.website.com/";
foreach( $ret as $row )
{
   echo "<h2><a href=" . $blogurl . $row->url . ">" . $row->title . "</a></h2>";
}
```

Comment: Yes, that is what I want to achieve, _to loop through each one_. Btw, I find that it is PDO that you use. How to use it with mysql?

Comment: Lots of docs / examples out there about [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php).

Comment: and how about <?php echo $blogurl; ?>, because I guess the link to the file is generated from there?